# Forward touch event to UITableView to produce inertia scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have been trying to forward touch events from one view to a `UITableView`. But I have come across a problem.

[image: prototype app to illustrate problem]

In the figure is a prototype view to illustrate the problem. The white view in the bottom half is a normal `UITableView`. The yellow view is a `UIView` that forwards touches to the middle of the `UITableView` using `hitTest:withEvent:`. The red view is a `UIButton`.

The goal is to forward the up and down panning touches from the yellow view to the `UITableView` at the bottom. However, tapping the red `UIButton` should still work.

I have tried 2 main approaches both of which have problems.

The first approach is to add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the yellow view that can be used to set the `contentOffset` of the `UITableView`. The problem is that inertial scrolling of the table view does not work with this approach.

The second approach is to forward touches using `hitTest:withEvent:` in the yellow view.

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if([self.button_red pointInside: [self convertPoint:point toView:self.button_red] withEvent:event]) {
        return self.button_red;
    } else {
        return [self.view_table hitTest:CGPointMake(self.view_table.width/2.0,self.view_table.height/2.0) withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

`hitTest:withEvent:` is only called when the touch starts in the yellow view. In other words, whenever a drag starts in the red view it won't forward the drag to the table view. Which is not good enough.

Is it possible to forward a pan gesture from the yellow view to the `UITableView` in a different way that keeps the red button working AND allows drags to work that start in the red button? Should I override the [touch event methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW3) in the yellow view to get this to work somehow? Is there way to do all this while keeping the inertial scrolling?

Comment: Can you not set yellowView as tableHeaderView on the UITableView?

Comment: That is a good idea but the refreshControl will end up at the top of the screen. I would like to keep the refreshControl below the yellow view

Comment: Okay, does the refreshControl also end up at top if we try something like. [tableView addSubview:yellowView]; [tableView setContentInset:CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(yellowView.frame))];

Comment: Great! It works! That's part of the idea, make it an answer and I'll edit your answer with the final piece of the puzzle. Then you can have the bounty.

Comment: I added the answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to add `yellowView` as a subview inside the `UITableView`.
2. You will also need to take care of the `contentInset` in order to
   accommodate for `yellowView` height.
3. By default, cells will appear over this added `yellowView`, you need
   to fix this by adjusting `zPosition` on the yellowView.

   ```
   CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(yellowView.frame);

   // fix yellowView's y position
   yellowView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -height, CGRectGetWidth(yellowView.frame), height); 

   [tableView addSubview:yellowView];
   yellowView.layer.zPosition = 10; // make it appear over cells

   [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(height, 0, 0, 0)];
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! I'm not sure if the zPosition is required, but it makes sense.